# Draw an arc with rounded corners on Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, kotlin, ondraw

I'm trying to implement a pie chart as shown in pictures below, where corners of the arc should be rounded.

[image: Arc with rounded corners]

[image: Arc with rounded corners]

I've tried to use `CornerPathEffect()`, but it seems to work only on the intersection of two lines (`path.lineTo()`). Nothing changes if I use this method for arc (`path.arcTo()`).

Answer (score 2):

Try to set Stroke Cap of paint.

```
mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
```

Comment: Already tried, it rounds the center point of the arc. What I need is rounded edges on the sides.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late for this answer but here is my solution.

**PieSlice.kt**

```
data class PieSlice(
    val name: String,
    var value: Double,
    var startAngle: Float,
    var sweepAngle: Float,
    var indicatorCircleLocation: PointF,
    val paint: Paint
)
```

**Function to make round corner arc**

```
private fun drawCurvedArc(canvas: Canvas?, pieItem: PieSlice) {
        val path = Path()

        path.moveTo(originX, originY)

        val angleStart = pieItem.startAngle

        val angleEnd = (pieItem.startAngle - pieItem.sweepAngle)

        val arcOffset = pieItem.sweepAngle.coerceAtMost(7f)
        val lineOffset = if (pieItem.sweepAngle < 7f) 0f else 25f

        // line from origin to top
        val line1x = getPointX(angleStart, lineOffset)
        val line1y = getPointY(angleStart, lineOffset)

        path.lineTo(line1x, line1y)


        //Curve corner from line top to arc start
        val arcStartx = getPointX(angleStart - arcOffset)
        val arcStarty = getPointY(angleStart - arcOffset)
        joinLineAndArc(path, line1x, line1y, arcStartx, arcStarty)


        //Arc
        path.arcTo(
            outerRect, (pieItem.startAngle - arcOffset),
            (-pieItem.sweepAngle + 2 * arcOffset), true
        )


        val line2x = getPointX(angleEnd, lineOffset)
        val line2y = getPointY(angleEnd, lineOffset)

        val arcEndx = getPointX(angleEnd + arcOffset)
        val arcEndy = getPointY(angleEnd + arcOffset)


        //Curve corner from arc end to bottom line
        joinLineAndArc(path, arcEndx, arcEndy, line2x, line2y)


        // Bottom line
        path.lineTo(originX, originY)


        val borderPaint = Paint()
        borderPaint.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        borderPaint.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        borderPaint.color = pieItem.paint.color
        borderPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        borderPaint.strokeWidth = 0f


        canvas?.drawPath(path, borderPaint)

    }

    /**
     * Join line and arc with a curve
     *
     * vector = (x1-x2,y1-y2)
     *
     * pVector perpendicular to vector
     *   pVector = (y1-y2,x2-x1)
     *
     *  midX = (x1+x2)/2
     *  midY = (y1+y2)/2
     *
     * (px,py) = (midX,midY) ± (D/√((y1−y2)^2,(x2−x1)^2))*(y1-y2,x2-x1)
     */
    private fun joinLineAndArc(
        path: Path,
        x1: Float,
        y1: Float,
        x2: Float,
        y2: Float
    ) {


        val midX: Float = (x2 + x1) / 2f
        val midY: Float = (y2 + y1) / 2f


        val x2_x1 = (x2 - x1).toDouble()
        val y1_y2 = (y1 - y2).toDouble()

        val powY = y1_y2.pow(2.0)
        val powX = x2_x1.pow(2.0)
        val den = sqrt(powY + powX)

        val len = 20.0

        // perpendicular1
        val p1x = (midX + ((len * y1_y2) / den)).toFloat()
        val p1y = (midY + ((len * x2_x1) / den)).toFloat()

        // perpendicular2
        val p2x = (midX - ((len * y1_y2) / den)).toFloat()
        val p2y = (midY - ((len * x2_x1) / den)).toFloat()

        val len1 = Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow((originX - p1x).toDouble(), 2.0)
                    + Math.pow((originY - p1y).toDouble(), 2.0)
        )

        val len2 = Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow((originX - p2x).toDouble(), 2.0)
                    + Math.pow((originY - p2y).toDouble(), 2.0)
        )

        //Make a curve to the point which is far from origin
        if (len1 > len2) {
            path.cubicTo(x1, y1, p1x, p1y, x2, y2)
        } else {
            path.cubicTo(x1, y1, p2x, p2y, x2, y2)
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get the x coordinate on a circle
     * formula for x pos: (radius) * cos(angle) + (distance from left edge of screen)
     * @param angle angle of point from origin
     * @param offset to make shorter line than actual radius
     */
    private fun getPointX(angle: Float, offset: Float = 0f): Float {
        return ((radius - offset)
                * cos(Math.toRadians((angle.toDouble())))
                + originX).toFloat()
    }

    /**
     * Get the y coordinate on a circle
     * formula for y pos: (radius) * sin(angle) + (distance from top edge of screen)
     *
     * @param angle angle of point from origin
     * @param offset to make shorter line than actual radius
     */
    private fun getPointY(angle: Float, offset: Float = 0f): Float {
        return ((radius - offset)
                * sin(Math.toRadians((angle.toDouble())))
                + originY).toFloat()

    }
```